# How to update Shop Metafields using GraphQL in Shopify

Tags: graphql, shopify, shopify-api

How can I create/update a shop metafield using GraphQL in shopify?
I could easily create a collection metafield using the following:

```
mutation {
  collectionUpdate(
    input: {
      id: "gid"
      metafields: [
        {
          namespace: "testNamespace"
          key: "testKey"
          value: "someValue2"
          valueType: STRING
        }
        {
          id: "gid"
          value: "value"
        }
      ]
    }
  ) {
    collection {
      id
      metafields(first: 10) {
        edges {
          node {
            id
            value
          }
        }
      }
    }
    userErrors {
        field
        message
      }
  }
}
```

But there seems to be no equivalent for the shop.
Also, a shop metafield can be retrieved using:

```
{
  shop {
    metafield(namespace:"namespace",key:"key") {
          id
          value
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tought that "global" metafields were the same as the ones on the shop object

Answer (score 5):

To Update any metafield you can use the mutation "**metafieldsSet**"

```
mutation setMetafield($metafields: [MetafieldsSetInput!]!) {
  metafieldsSet(metafields:$metafields){
    metafields{
      id
      key
      value
    }
    userErrors{
      code
      message
    }
  }
}
```

**MetafieldsSetInput** Requires owner id which you can get from shop query

```
query shopDetails{
  shop{
    id
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, saved me some time the ownerID was very confusing